# Applying discount to products based on 2 criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of clothing products and I want to allocate a discount code to each product based on 2 criteria.

Column A is the product description, column B is the clothing season, column C is where the discount code should be generated. Then I have a table which has the rules for the discount codes: season in column F, product type in column G, and discount code in column H. Here's the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zwjjs55BFBtKYJdoznsjXQXGDRWpUs7lQ5lm2tnuUR4/edit?usp=sharing

So if a product is a summer t-shirt then it should be given the discount code "AAA". If the product doesn't match this then I want to continue down the discounts codes table until one of the season and product type combinations matches. The discount codes need to be applied following the strict order of the discount codes table.

I can achieve this by using the IFS formula but this requires making the formula longer and longer for each extra discount code I add to the table.

`=IFS( AND(B3=$F$3,REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A3),LOWER($G$3))),$H$3 , AND(B3=$F$4,REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A3),LOWER($G$4))),$H$4 )`

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Tim B, try clearing Column C entirely (including the header) and placing the following formula into C2:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Discount Code";IF(A3:A="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UPPER(B3:B)&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(UPPER(A3:A),TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,UPPER(G2:G)))),{UPPER(F3:F&G3:G),H3:H},2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UPPER(B3:B)&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A3:A),IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(UPPER(A3:A),TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,UPPER(G2:G)))),""),TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,UPPER(G2:G)))),{UPPER(F3:F&G3:G),H3:H},2,FALSE),)))})
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for closing the loop here. Enjoy.